# How std::set::emplace_hint() actually speeds up the insertion process?

Tags: c++, stl

I don't understand(despite having comments)how the emplace_hint() function works,How an emplace_hint() actually speeds up the insertion process?Could someone explain me the code?

```
// CPP program to demonstrate the 
// set::emplace_hint() function 
#include <iostream>
#include <set> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 

  set<int> s; 
  auto it = s.emplace_hint(s.begin(), 1); 

    /* stores the position of 2's insertion*/ 
    it = s.emplace_hint(it, 2); 

    /* fast step as it directly 
    starts the search step from 
    position where 3 was last inserted */
    s.emplace_hint(it, 3); 

    /* this is a slower step as 
    it starts checking from the 
    position where 3 was inserted 
    but 0 is to be inserted before 1 */
    s.emplace_hint(it, 0); 

    /* prints the set elements*/ 
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) 
        cout << *it << " "; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` is usually implemented as a balanced binary search tree. Normally, `set::insert` would need to search the tree to find an appropriate insertion point for the new element, which takes `O(log N)` time. But if the caller can provide a correct spot for insertion - namely, an iterator to an existing element that would be adjacent to the new one - then this search can be avoided, and insertion can be done in O(1) time.

`emplace_hint` gives the caller the opportunity to provide that iterator.

Comment: Yes,but I still have a small doubt,in line `it = s.emplace_hint(s.begin(),  1);` iterator `it` stores the position of element 1 right?,then in the next line the iterator `it` stores the position of 2,same like the above line,then when the next line executes(i.e inserting 3) `s.emplace_hint(it, 3)`,will the iterator points to the new element 3 (or) will the iterator  still keeps pointing to last element inserted i.e 2?

Comment: Since `it` wasn't assigned to, it would keep its previous value, and continue to refer to element 2.